# Where is the line between Game Development and Stack Overflow? Should I transfer this topic to SO?

Tags: discussion

I have [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/125465/how-am-i-supposed-to-tilmestep-this-gravitational-simulator) topic that hasn't received an answer. That could be because my method is too unorthodox, the problem too big, or a badly worded question. I am in no way frustrated about this because it has only been one day, and is a complicated problem.

But one thing I was considering is if it would do better in SO where things are more coding based, and conversations about time stepping are more common. Since this question was more coding/math/physics based where does it belong the most? In some ways I could almost see it at SE Mathematics. What is the line between Game Development and SO topics that involve code for games?

What if this topic did really belong in another site. I think it would be rude to copy and paste it into another site (that would essentially be double posting), is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is fine here.

The "line" isn't very firm. There is definitely a lot of overlap between certain topics here and on SO, and that is fine. Our general rules, which  definitely have fuzzy subjective parts, are:

- does this have *anything at all* do with making a game?
- would a game developer give you a better answer to this question than a non-game developer?

If the answers to both of those are a resounding "no," we migrate to SO. Otherwise it's perfectly fine here.

Your question is only 23 hours old, it's not languishing or anything. I suspect the issue with it will be that it's a fairly dense wall of text and code, followed by whats amounts to "where do I stick some math?" It's fairly imposing and hard to wrap your head around, which means the expected investment from any given potential answer-er must be more. Which generally means fewer attempts at answers.

I suspect you'd get better responses if you were able to streamline the question somehow. I'm not necessarily convinced you'd get better responses on SO, but until the question has an answer here you're free to delete it and re-post it there.